# CustomDialog vs. Activity with theme.dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I need a dialog with 2 text views and about 8 buttons + ok and cancel button. Pressing one of 8 buttons should change text views. Ok button should return last pressed button and cancel should return a special value.

I think that for this is better a special activity than a custom dialog but I have a problem with returning a last switched button.

```
handler = new Handler() {
        @Override 
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Spellbook.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

I'm not starting the activity from the main thread so I have to use a handler but I don't know how can I start the activity with response there. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just having an issue getting the value back from the started activity?

If so you just need to handle the `onActivityResult()` method on the `Activity` that is used as the context for the new `Intent` and make sure in the called `Activity` that you use `setResult()` and `finish()`..

In the called `Activity`..

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, /* Some Intent with Data should go here */ null);
finish();
```

In the calling `Activity`..

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    /* Handle result and extract data from Intent */
}
```

Comment: "Are you just having an issue getting the value back from the started activity?" Yes and the issue is that I dont know how to call startActivityForResult from my own thread. Using context I can call only startActivity method.

Comment: @Houp I understand but is that not your context is from to begin with? If so you could cast `((Activity)context).startActivityForResult()`. If you are using something else (like a more global application context) then you will not be able to do this and might want to refactor to pass the activity context if possible, otherwise you might have to use a more accessible object for interaction.

Comment: Thank you Quintin, this is working. However, why is necessary to convert context to Activity class? Why context class hasn't method startActivityForResult?

Comment: @Houp You bet, glad it is working. I wish I could tell you the reason for the generic `Context` class not having the `startActivityForResult()` method but I must confess that I have not investigated the implementation to determine the exact reason. My assumption would be that the `Context` is meant to be lightweight and not encumbered by all the data necessary to interact with an `Activity`.

Comment: @Houp I also noticed you are new here, to help the community and the future inquirers in resolving their issues in a quick manner you should mark the answer that resolved your issue as the accepted answer. You can review the faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) as to how to accomplish this and for further etiquette on stackoverflow, welcome to the community!